# VBA to open two workbooks from first workbook and select specific sheet in second workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open two workbooks from my first workbook which contains the VBA and then activate a specific sheet in the second workbook. The code is below but for some reason the sheet in the second workbook does not get activated. As the files will vary in name and location I have made them a reference in the VBA file so that they can be changed on the front end rather than in the code.

The code is below:

```
Sub OpenWorkbooks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim srcFle, dataFle As String
Dim wb, wb1, wb2 As Workbook

srcFle = ActiveSheet.Range("C7").Value
dataFle = ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(srcFle)
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(dataFle)

wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Select`?

Comment: Thanks Dean, I tried your suggestion but it generates a run-time error 1004 message saying select method of worksheet class failed.

Comment: Are you sure that worksheet exists in `wb1`?

Comment: Right, think you need to activate `wb1` before, activating/ selecting the sheet. So `wb1.Activate` then my line above should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the activation of the 2nd workbook

```
Sub OpenWorkbooks()

On Error goto CleanUp  '<--- This will restore your screen update in case of error
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim srcFle, dataFle As String
Dim wb, wb1, wb2 As Workbook

srcFle = ActiveSheet.Range("C7").Value
dataFle = ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(srcFle)
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(dataFle)

wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate   '<--- You need this line to activate the 2nd workbook

CleanUp:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Hope this is what you need. Just let me know if you need further help!

Comment: Hi Tsiriniaina, sorry to say that didn't work either.

Comment: No worry, that's the first step. Now what do you want to do with Activate because it is not recommended to use Activated in your codes?

Comment: Basically all I want to do is open two workbooks from the original VBA file - one workbook is the source file where the data needs to end up and the other is the file that contains the data that needs to be copied from. Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: Could you update your question including a screenshot of the Source Columns and Destination Columns please so I can update the code to match your need?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub OpenWorkbooks()

'    ' You have declared srcFle as Variant
'    Dim srcFle, dataFle As String
'    ' You have declared wb and wb1 as Variant
'    Dim wb, wb1, wb2 As Workbook

'    ' This is how it's done:
'    Dim srcFle As String, dataFle As String
'    Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

    ' But best is briefly describing or naming the variables:
    Dim srcFle As String    ' Source Workbook Name
    Dim dataFle As String   ' Data Workbook Name
    Dim wb As Workbook      ' This Workbook
    Dim wb1 As Workbook     ' Source Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook     ' Data Workbook

    ' Retrieve Target Workbook Names from This Workbook.
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    srcFle = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("C7").Value
    dataFle = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value
'    ' better is e.g.:
'    srcFle = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C7").Value
'    dataFle = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C10").Value

    ' Open Target Workbooks (wb1, wb2)
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(srcFle)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(dataFle)

    ' Prepare to work in Source Workbook (wb1).
    wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll give this a go and let you know how I get on. Many thanks for the suggestions.